# Ambiguous behaviour of NaN and 0 in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan, zero

In a dataframe I have columns of integers (0 and theoretically 1, but it doesn't occur so far) and NaN. When I filter for the 0 or NaN values, I get a weird behaviour where the

```
df_filtered = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('TestID47')]
df_filtered = df_filtered[df_filtered != 0]
df_filtered.head(3)
```

Results in:

```
TestID47    TestID472   TestID475   TestID478
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN

df_filtered2 = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('TestID47')]
df_filtered2 = df_filtered2[df_filtered2 != np.nan]
df_filtered2.head(3)
```

Results in:

```
TestID47    TestID472   TestID475   TestID478
0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0
1   0   0.0 0.0 0.0
2   0   0.0 0.0 0.0
```

The dtypes pf df_filtered2 are like this, which should explain the different 0 / 0.0:

```
TestID47       int64
TestID472    float64
TestID475    float64
TestID478    float64
```

What am I doing wrong or missing? Is this behaviour somehow expected? Since NaN is always FALSE and I need the 0 to be something different than NaN, this is not working for me.

Comment: Don't compare to `np.nan` using `==` or `!=`, since `np.nan == np.nan` is `False`. Use `pd.isnull(something)` instead

Comment: what is the problem? you filter nan and get zeros, and you filter zeros you get nan, can you clarify what was your expectation

Comment: My expectation was to get exactly what I filter for, as with any other character or value - not a "mutating" result, since in my data 0 and nan is very different.

Thanks rafaelc, that explains a lot. :)